# How to fix tesseract invalid output in some particular case?

Tags: opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1.
I am using

```
 tesseract filename.jpg - --psm 6
```

as command to get output.
But,i get wrong output. Input file in image in jpg format.
I have tried with following image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OO26.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2euvY.jpg 
                    mQkAl8B

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsn6Z.jpg

```
tesseract filename.jpg - --psm 6
```

I was expecting following output for each image:
a)==
c)->
d)()
But,actual output is following:
A) ==
Cc) ->
cd) ( )

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mQkAl8B
I was unable to add image so i have one image here.

Comment: I think the problem can be due to cropping. If possible, add some padding among the text so that text will have some bounding white padding space.